# How to deserialize JSON to only "built-in" types

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

Firstly, I'm *so* sorry to ask another question about JSON deserialization. I haven't seen an answer for this, however.

I'd like to deserialize JSON to `T` where `T` is defined recursively as:

- `Dictionary<string, T>`
- `T[]`
- `string`
- a primitive type
- `(object)T` (boxed)

I know many of the JSON libraries out there allow specifying the deserialized type, but, in my experience, some custom type (`JObject`, `JsonObject`, whatever) shows up somewhere in the object graph (that is, the return type only seems to be applied to a certain depth). It seems straighforward since the types map almost one-to-one with JavaScript's.

**EDIT**

Ideally, I'd like the JSON to be "clean," that is, no special fields ("__type," etc) to aid in deserialization. It should be a straightforward mapping from JavaScript: `JObject` -> `IDictionary<string, T>`, `JArray` -> `T[]`, and so on.

In the meantime, I'm using an FParsec parser and a hand-rolled serializer. It works great, but I thought there might be something for this already out there.

Comment: have you tried Newtonsoft.JSON? (http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) This is used by ravenDB and I havent had issues during deserialization.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm using at the moment and `JObject`'s invariably appear in deeply nested object graphs.

Comment: could you provide some example code and input data?

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure as to what you mean by "I'd like to deserialize JSON to T where T is defined recursively as" my assumption is that you want to be able to serialize and de-serialize any of the types listed above and in any combination.

My experience has shown that the standard DotNet libraries available in `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json` specifically `DataContractJsonSerializer` are more then adequate for the job you describe and will successfully deal with all the types you mention (with no meta data descriptions) other then one; a boxed object of T. However my assumption is that no library would be able to deal with a boxed object of T without providing meta data (How can it? It knows nothing about your object)

Here is some code that I use to provide serialization in my apps

```
public class JSONSerializer<T>
{

    public static string Serialize(T obj)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()) {
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, obj);
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(stream.ToArray());
        }
    }

    public static T Deserialize(string json)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(json))) {
            return (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
        }
    }

}
```

PS: Also note that the DataContractSerializer does a "pure" serialization and deserialization without using any proxy type objects (at least not in the output or input, perhaps somewhere internally).

Comment: I tried to serialize a class that implements `IDictionary<string, object>` and it barfs. It must check the run-time type (`this.GetType()`) instead of `typeof(Dictionary<string, object>).IsAssignableFrom(type)`.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use generic. That is because generic have to be at compile time stripped to one single type. But JSON objects or arrays values shoudl be any JSON type and that is confict.

But if you want you can use `object` and then cast it. JSON arrays are `object[]` and JSON objects are `Dictionary<string,object>`. But this is only an variation on custom type you mentioned.